# What is the equivalent to the VBArray Object in Chromium?

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer, chromium, safearray

I need to be able to convert a VBArray to a JavaScript Array using a Chromium JavaScript engine. This means the old IE method of `var javascriptArray = new VBArray(input).toArray();` will not work. What would be alternatives to this?

In other words, is there a way to change a SafeArrays into a JavaScript array in newer versions of JavaScript on Edge?

Comment: I do not believe there is a direct equivalent. You could create an object which behaves like that, or [use an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Comment: I've had issues trying both objects and arrays. Javascript seems to have difficulty reading the data present. Even the typeof returns "unknown".

Comment: Reading what data?

Comment: I cannot set it to an Object or Array, iterate through it, or detect it's type. My code knows an object is there, but throws Type mismatch when I try to perform operations on it.

Comment: What is a SafeArray when it comes to JavaScript? I don't think newer JS engines have any concept of a SafeArray

Comment: That's the issue I'm facing. JS detects the existence of an object, but doesn't have any methods to deal with it.

Comment: May you provide a text-based [mcve]?

Comment: I am receiving a SafeArray from an internal object created by our development team.  I am unsure how to put an example other than how I handle it. Using JScript on IE, to obtain a JavaScript Array from a SafeArray,  you can use var jsArray = new VBArray(input).toArray();